# Azure Functions not recognizing my functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure functions
Core Tools: 4.0.5095
Function Runtime Version: 4.16.5.20396

Whenever I test my functions locally or deploy them to the server, it does not recognize my functions at all. In verbose mode, it prints the following: [image]

This works:

```
host.json
package.json
myFunc/
  - myFunc.ts
  - function.json
```

This does NOT work:

```
host.json
package.json
src/
  - myFunc/
    -- myFunc.ts
    -- function.json
```

I would like my code placed in a tidy `src/` directory, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I've tried the following, to no avail:

- modifying the `function.json` to point to the correct directory, ex: `"scriptFile": "../../dist/function1/index.js"`.
- adding a `FUNCTIONS_PATHS` variable to my local.settings.json to point to the `src/` directory.
- moving the `host.json` into the `src/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions not recognizing my functions

> using the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?pivots=programming-language-javascript&tabs=python-v2,in-process,functionsv2) i was able to create the trigger based your requirement working locally and in Azure like below:-
>
> ```
> host.json
> package.json
> src/
> - myFunc/
>  -- myFunc.ts
>  -- function.json
> ```
>
> ```js
> import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from  "@azure/functions"
> const  httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async  function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
> context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
> const  name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
> const  responseMessage = name
> ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
> : " Include a name in the request body or query string..";
> context.res = {
> // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
> body:  responseMessage
> };
> };
> export  default  httpTrigger;
> ```

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://microsoft.github.io/MicrosoftCloud/tutorials/docs/Automate-Data-Reporting-with-Azure-Functions-and-Power-Automate/Convert-Local-Script-Code-into-an-Azure-Function/) for deployment.
> Make sure the respective [files](https://i.imgur.com/PeKCA87.png) are present in [Environment](https://i.imgur.com/VEJVztN.png).

[image]
Output:

[image]

Azure Output :

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the response! I was hoping I could have the function folders a directory deeper than the host.json, package.json, package-lock.json, local.settings.json, tsconfig.json, etc since they are more data than source code, but it looks like that's not a possibility. Thanks!